# how to get UK pincode list

Tags: android, maps

I want to type an address in a field as string and want to get POSTCODE (Only apply for UK) according to it. Is there any free API which provide me the details or is there any database which can be downloaded for getting UK POSTCODE list and may helps Me to provide suggession when the user'll type the address.

Comment: I don't believe you'll find any free API. As you can see from NickT link the post-offce raw data cost £75 an year and I applied before this API http://www.craftyclicks.co.uk/ in a work project which the company have to pay to access. This API works ok, but it's XML only which is annoying to parse, but doable.

Comment: Thanks Sir, but I prefer json data if I got. Anyway, thanks for paying attention, I'll try for it.

Comment: I would prefer json as well, if you find one let me know.

Comment: I don't find any free of cost API yet, but I found a .csv file which have all the postcodes for UK. U can put this file in your project and able to fetch all the records and manage a database or anything else according to You.By this, You are able to provide suggession in your typing field.

Comment: sounds like a good enough plan. I probably can script some to turn into an actual SQLite instance. Do you have a link of it?

Comment: yes I found a link last day

Comment: Would you like to share the link me, so I can have it too?

Comment: yes, why not... I have this csv file, but lost the link buddy... i need to search it again?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you mean postcode not pincode. In that case the only guaranteed correct data is from [The Royal Mail](http://www.royalmail.com/marketing-services/address-management-unit/address-data-products/postcode-address-file-paf?campaignid=paf_redirect)

Comment: yes, its postcode... is this possible to use the information in my android application which I got from the link u suggest?

Comment: It might be tricky getting as it's just a file and not an API, so it will be BIG. Also I forgot to point out, it's not free as Budius pointed out

Comment: I can manage if its a DB or a kind of file, my intention is just to get all the UK postcode, and provide suggession at the time of typing the address like google provide on its main page.